# ConfigurationErrorsException on .NET 3.5 when SP1 installed

Tags: asp.net, deployment, iis-7, .net-3.5

I am getting an exception in my deployed ASP.NET application on Windows Server 2008 R2 when .NET 3.5 SP1 is installed.  If I install it with 3.5 it works perfectly well, as soon as I install SP1 it falls over with the following exception.

```
Exception type: ConfigurationErrorsException 
Exception message: Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
    at System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase)
    at System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, Boolean checkAptcaBit)
    at System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry.SecureGetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement)
    at System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry..ctor(String name, String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement)
    ... etc
```

What on earth is happening?

**Update**

Running `aspnet_regiis.exe -iru` after installing SP1 fixes things but I still would like a method that doesnt require a manual intervention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a similar problem 6-8 months ago but i resolved it by specifying `iru` parameter while running aspnet_regiis.exe(based on some post I saw from the internet). I am not sure if
its the same problem but you can try that if you want.

**Update :** This might help :[Code project link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/296204/Could-not-load-type-System-ServiceModel-Activation)

Comment: Looks very promising, what does that flag actually do?

Comment: As far as i know -iru will update the existing application pools to the version of asp.net you are installing. You can go throught this msdn documentation incase you are curious : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately this doesnt work.  Note the order I do things is: Install 3.5 > Install my app > Install SP1.  Perhaps this only works when you are installing after SP1 is on?